# bundle install error because of therubyracer gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bundle

I'm using rails 4.1.4 and ruby-2.1.1. My Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'

gem 'devise'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
gem 'aws-sdk'

gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'

gem 'jquery-tokeninput-rails'

gem 'carmen-rails'

gem 'will_paginate'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
gem 'byebug'
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# group :production do
#   gem "rails_12factor"
#   gem "activerecord-postgresql-adapter"
#   gem 'pg'
# end

gem 'activemerchant'
```

but whenever i run the `bundle install` command **Rubymine** said,

```
Gemfile:29: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
```

what should i do? If i commented out the "therubyracer" gem. Then this error shows for `sdoc` gem.

Comment: I don't think you need that parameter

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
```

Comment: Now the new error says "/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /var/lib/gems (Errno::EACCES)"

Comment: Run with administration rights
run sudo bundle install

Comment: don't bundle install with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your error traceback, you have Ruby 1.8 installed (OS default). Ruby on Rails 4.1 requires at least Ruby 1.9.3. So you can use [RVM](http://rvm.io) to install newer Ruby version. Then you'll be able to install all required gems. And using RVM or rbenv is recommended way to manage rubies nowadays.